# JoyX JoyY to SendInput

Tags: autohotkey

My joystick/gamepad has the standard 10 buttons plus the X and Y axis buttons. The script below works, but not the way I want it:

```
Right::
GetKeyState, state, JoyX
If state > 75 ;JoyX is pressed to right
SendInput testmessage
```

What this script will do is print "testmessage" when I press the right arrow key on my keyboard while JoyX is > 75. What I want is that, when JoyX is > 75, it will SendInput "testmessage" without having to press the right arrow key on my keyboard.

I tried using JoyX as hotkey, or X100 Y050, but I get an error message: the current hotkey JoyX will not be active bec it is not in the keyboard layout.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The joystick has a state that must be polled as it doesn't have a "button" event to respond to. The following used [Remapping a Joystick to Keyboard or Mouse](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RemapJoystick.htm) for inspiration, in particular the *Making a Joystick Axis or POV Hat Send Keystrokes or Mouse Clicks* section. It uses a timer to periodically poll the state of the joystick and sends the input when the state is >75.

```
#Persistent  ; Keep this script running until the user explicitly exits it.
SetTimer, WatchAxis, 5
return

WatchAxis:
GetKeyState, state, JoyX
If state > 75 ;JoyX is pressed to right
    SendInput testmessage
return
```

To get it to work well for you, you'll need to play around with the timer's poll frequency (currently 5) and may need to implement the `KeyToHoldDown` style of state tracking, otherwise you might send the text repeatedly.

Comment: Please note that this is currently untested, but I might try it later with an Xbox controller and see how it works.